# Get row with certain value from aggregate group, if a row with this value exists

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table where I'm doing a GROUP_CONCAT on column A which contains hash values. Each of the rows which are grouped together can contain different values in column B. Let's say column B can contain 'yes' or 'no'.

In case there are rows with 'yes' and 'no' in that group I would like to take 'yes' as the result of the grouping for column B. If I do nothing, according to the doc I will get a random result for column B.

I haven't found an aggregate function that accepts a fixed value/string. The function FIXED_VALUE is a non existing aggregate function I would like to see.

```
+--------+---------+
|  hash  |  yes_no |
+--------+---------+
| 111111 |    yes  |
| 111111 |    no   |
| 111111 |    no   |
| 222222 |    no   |
| 222222 |    no   |
+--------+---------+

SELECT FIXED_VALUE(yes_no='yes') FROM my_table GROUP BY hash
```

Comment: can you post some data and the attempt you have made?

Comment: Just added more details. Thanks!

Comment: there is no function called FIXED_VALUE in mysql. look at the answer I posted I also posted a demo that shows it working.

Comment: i just edited my answer with a better way to do it. just use the MAX() aggregate on the yes_no

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this.

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(hash) as hash,
    MAX(yes_no) as yes_no
FROM table
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed689/5)

Comment: Yes I know that FIXED_VALUE does not exist. Like I said, this is just a function I would like to have. The Problem with the MAX() solution is that it is thought for numbers. So by chance it might calculate something useful for strings as well. But if I not only have two values, this function is useless. 'yes' / 'no' was only an example.

Comment: @Bernd i need a better understanding on what you want to show like what the strings would be... is it more than two? and what would the order be for each one?

Comment: John, thanks for your reply. The important point is: I want a certain value to be taken in case it exists. If I wouldn't choose a certain value, according to the doc I would end up in having an undefined result. That means that any of all available values might be taken as a result. My real case is the following (I just wanted to simplify before): I have 3 values: "pref_go", "pref_nogo", "on". When grouping, only "pref_go" and "on" can occur at the same time in a group. But when both of them indeed exist, I need to make sure that "pref_go" (and not "on") is taken. Thx!